# Android AlarmManager PendingIntent is launched before call to alarm.set()

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I've read about every similar question on here but cannot find an answer, so please forgive me if this has been answered before, I really tried to search.

I'm setting up an alarm to show a notification after a certain time. The time logic is definitely solid, I can tell by my log output, this is not the problem.

I create a Pending intent like so:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(c, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.putExtra("title", name);
alarmIntent.putExtra("location", building);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
```

and then set the alarm to fire after `millis` milliseconds. In this instance, `millis` is `407603959` according to my log statements. It definitely should not be firing after one second.

```
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis, pi);
Log.i("Alarm", "Alarm: " + name + " is set for: "
        + untilAlarm.getDays() + " days, " + untilAlarm.getHours() + " hours, "
        + untilAlarm.getMinutes() + " minutes from now. Or, " + millis 
        + " milliseconds");
```

It appears as though my PendingIntent is being started before the alarm is even set. I tried blocking an alarm from being created like so:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(c, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.putExtra("title", name);
alarmIntent.putExtra("location", building);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, alarmIntent, 
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

if (!name.equals("test") {
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis, pi);
    //Log statement...
}
```

and the alarm for `test` is still triggered, but the log statement is not printed to the console, meaning `alarm.set` was never called. The intent is still fired, and a notification is shown with the title "test".

Why is my PendingIntent being launched before the alarm is fired?

Comment: For an `RTC` alarm, 407603959 milliseconds is _waaaay_ in the past, so the alarm should fire pretty much immediately when set. Not really enough info to determine if/why it's firing without being set.

Comment: Oh right, I guess it should be Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + mills then?

Comment: Yeah, if you want it to fire 407603959 milliseconds in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an alarm type of `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`, which will set the alarm to start at a specified time, in your case `millis`.

To set the alarm to start at a certain amount of time in the future, you need to either use one of these types of elapsed-time alarms:

- **ELAPSED_REALTIME**

*Alarm time in SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() (time since boot,
   including sleep). This alarm does not wake the device up; if it goes
   off while the device is asleep, it will not be delivered until the
   next time the device wakes up.*

- **ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP**

*Alarm time in SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() (time since boot,
   including sleep), which will wake up the device when it goes off.*

Or use an `RTC` or `RTC_WAKEUP` with the current time plus the time to wait, like:

```
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + millis, pi);
```

Comment: yup. That did it. Side note I had to make my pending intent with the ONE_SHOT flag to ensure the correct extra strings were passed if I created a second alarm. I'll edit the question for future reference

Comment: "current time plus the time to wait"  this work for me when RTC_WAKEUP... thanks bro